# merging two column

Tags: sed, awk, merge

input_file (columns are tab delimited, only column 4 contains spaces)

**input**

```
A B C D;<>X;<>Y 0
C D E F;<>Z;<>X 1
```

**output**

```
A B C D;<>X;<>Y;<>apple=0
C D E F;<>Z;<>X;<>apple=1
```

I would like to merge the last column of input_file with the second last column and separate the value of last column with ";" and a tag "apple=" in second last column (just like in column number 4 of input_file). Hence that output_file has one less column. It is also necessary to keep the formatting output file to be intact.As all the columns are tab delimited, but the values in column 4 has spaces too (D;<>X;<>Y).

Hence I want to keep all the field separators of input file as such,  just want to merge the value of last column in the second last with a tag (apple=). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the last but one field and removing the last field:

```
$ awk '{$(NF-1)=$(NF-1)";<>apple="$NF;$NF="";}1' OFS="\t" file
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} { $4 = $4 ";<>apple="$5; print $1, $2, $3, $4 }'
```

The `BEGIN` block ensures that tab is used as input field separator as well as output separator.